# LDAP issue, ldap_bind invalid dn syntax

Tags: php, ldap

I know that my mistake is going to be something really simple but I have tried to find the problem and I do not see it, maybe you can help me....

I am trying to create a function with php, so I can be able to connect to LDAP and find the desired information.

My php code is the following:

```
$ldapconfig['host'] = "127.0.0.1";
$ldapconfig['port'] = NULL;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = "dc=example,dc=com";
$ldapconfig['binddn'] = "user";
$ldapconfig['bindpw'] = "password";


function ldap_authenticate($user, $pass) {
global $ldapconfig;
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7); 
if ($user != "" && $pass != "") {
    $ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'],$ldapconfig['port']);
    if(!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_bind( $ds, $ldapconfig['binddn'], $ldapconfig['bindpw']);
    $r = ldap_search( $ds, $ldapconfig['basedn'], 'sAMAccountName=' . $user);
    if ($r) {
        $result = ldap_get_entries( $ds, $r);
        if ($result[0]) {
            if (ldap_bind( $ds, $result[0]['dn'], $pass) ) {
                return $result[0]['mail'][0];
            }
        }
    }
}
return NULL;
```

When I try to run the code it gives me the following mistake:
ldap_bind invalid DN syntax on line xxxx
and that line is the following:

```
ldap_bind( $ds, $ldapconfig['binddn'], $ldapconfig['bindpw']);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in the error, your bind DN is the wrong format. DN's represent the full path to the object - so in your case should be something like this (looks like you're on AD?)

"cn=username,ou=domain users,dc=example,dc=com"

Depending on your flavor of LDAP (Active Directory, OpenLDAP etc), you *might* be able to use a uid (so just 'username') to bind, but it's best to assume that you always need the full DN.

You can use an LDAP tool like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to help build queries and find out what object's DN's are. Or there's [ldp.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224543) too (provided it's AD), but directory studio is easier to use.

Comment: For the simple authentication method, the DN is required. For certain SASL methods, a username or distinguished name is required.

Comment: Thnaks for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to use a __custom__ (i.e. selected by me) attribute as username to login? e.g. the `mail` attribute of `inetOrgPerson` object class? (using `OpenLDAP`)

Answer (score 1):

On a DC, Executing:
dsquery user -samid jim

will reveal the DN of the user matching the sAMAccountName:
"CN=Jim Willeke,CN=Users,DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com"

http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20and%20Active%20Directory