# Active Directory connection

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need a small help. I am new to active directory. I want to connect my active directory with c#. Here is the sample code i have wrote.

```
 public void GetConnection()
    {
        var username = "xxxx";
        var domain = "xxxx";
        var password = "xxxx";
        var path = "LDAP://xxxx/CN=xx";

        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(sDomain + "/" + sDefaultOU, sUsername, sServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        //Include subtrees
        ds.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree;
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";

        //Fetch all results that match the directory entry (domain)

        var sr = ds.FindAll();

        if (sr != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        }
    }
```

The error is:

cannot implicitly convert type 'system.directoryservices.protocols.searchscope' to 'system.directoryservices.searchscope'. an explicit conversion exits.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you check if, instead of using a `LDAP` path on your initialization, the error gone using an existing Active Directory Server name directly? I mean, `var path = "<serverName>"`

Comment: @HuorSwords i tried doing it. That issue is fixed. But another bug is displaying in "using (var searcher=...)" as an invalied dn syntax has been specified

Comment: Then you must update your question or answer the first issue with your solution and open a new question to your second issue or... you can check this answer to your [second issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488785/982431). I think it fits with your problem.