# Connecting to OpenLDAP server using C#

Tags: c#, ldap, openldap

I have setup OpenLDAP server on CentOS7 and I am trying to connect to this LDAP server and do search on it. Simple C# program. This works with Active Directory, but I am unable to search on OpenLDAP.

```
  txtUsername.Text = "cn=ldapadm,dc=field,dc=linuxhostsupport,dc=com";
  txtPassword.Text = "password";
  txtLDAPPort.Text = "389";
  txtBaseDN.Text = "dc=linuxhostsupport,dc=com";

  string DomainPath = String.Format("LDAP://{0}:{1}/{2}", txtLDAPServer.Text, txtLDAPPort.Text, txtBaseDN.Text);
  DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
  DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
  search.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";
  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
  SearchResult result;
  SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
```

I am getting exception -

```
  An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()
  at LDAPSearchTest.Form1.btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

What I am missing here?

I have referred https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-ldap-on-centos-7/ to setup OpenLDAP.

Regards
Nilesh

Comment: The error is pretty clear. DN Syntax.  Are you missing "ou=someOrgUnit"?  Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488785/11605410

Comment: Problem is resolved. I was using NTLM authentication( found out in OpenLDAP logs). With anonymous authentication, authentication is successful and search is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost AuthenticationTypes.

Mark:

> DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath,
> txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text,AuthenticationTypes.None);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).